# Notify about dupes of a favorite question when it has answers

Tags: feature-request, notifications, bookmarks, favorites-notifications, duplicate-questions

If a post *(A)* is closed as a duplicate of another one *(B)*, and post A has answers, people who have favorited post B should be notified because those answers may also be useful.

Comment: I find this unclear. Is the suggestion "when user A favorites question N, and later question M is closed as a dup of N, notify user A of the existence of M (but only if M has answers)"?

Comment: @dmckee: exactly that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is:

- Fairly complicated to implement
- Fairly complicated to explain and understand
- Although somewhat useful, not very

Overall I just don't think it's worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Not a bad idea, but I suspect there are many things that should come first.